# Unknown proccess listening on udp port 53

Tags: network, unix

I was trying to start `dnscrypy-proxy` on my local machine to listen on its private ip address for use in my homenetwork, but it fails to start saying `listen udp 192.168.0.2:53: bind: address already in use`. Running `sudo lsof -P|grep :53` shows no proccess listening on port 53, and running `netstat -vanp udp` gives this as its output (truncated for only port 53):

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)     rhiwat shiwat    pid   epid  state    options
udp46      0      0  *.53                   *.*                                  4096   4096  33571      0 0x0180 0x00000020
```

However, there is no such pid given when running `sudo ps aux` or scanning through the output of `sudo htop`. As a last resort, I tried `sudo kill -15 33571`, which simply replied `kill: 33571: No such process`. Does anyone know how I could find what is actually listening on this port?

Comment: Do the answers at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66158 help?

Comment: No, however from further testing, I suspect the issue was due to dnscrypt-proxy not shutting down properly, though after rebooting my system a few times, I can no longer reproduce the issue.